# CMake не видит contribute модули для OpenCV

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv

Ставлю под `Ubuntu 18.04`. Устанваливаю полностью по [мануалу](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html), с добавлением флага `-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules` во время сборки. Ошибок не возникает, после установки хэдеры и библиотеки модулей лежат в  `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2` и `/usr/local/lib` соответственно.

При этом `pkg-config --cflags opencv` выдаёт:

```
-I/usr/include/opencv
```

Другими словами модулей он не видит. Если собираю через `CMake` с командой

```
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

То ругается на отсутствие модуля (из-за прописанного в коде #ifdef HAVE_OPENCV_XFEATURES2D).

При попытке ручного сбора через `g++`:

```
g++ FeatureDetector_example.cpp -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -L/usr/local/lib
```

Получаю пачку `undefined reference`. В чём может быть причина и возможный фикс?

Comment: При сборке посредством g++ вы не линкуете библиотеку.  `-L/usr/local/lib` не имеет смысла, так как этот путь встроенный

Comment: Вероятно надо добавить `-lopencv**.a` в строку сборки руками. Звёздочки изменить на полное имя без префикса `lib`